# Slider image in bootstrap website not fitting in mobile view

Tags: html, jquery, css, image, bootstrap-4

I have a slider in my bootstrap website, a link to the website is [here](http://yantraev.com/)

The slider image is working fine in desktop devices, but in mobile it's not fitting into screen, I did the following css:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
.n2-ss-slider [data-mode=fill] .n2-ss-slide-background-image {
    background-size: 400px !important;
}
```

This css was working fine yesterday, now it's not working, can anyone please tell me how to make the slider image fit into screen in mobile view, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can tell, this is the CSS responsible for making the images `cover` (i.e. cover the whole panel, which makes the height of the image match the height of the panel, pushing the left and right edges off screen).

```
.n2-ss-slider .n2-ss-slide-background-image img {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

If you add this CSS, you should be able to override it:

```
.n2-ss-slider .n2-ss-slide-background-image img {
    object-fit: fill;
}
```